# Why am I getting a break in the output of this WHERE loop?

Tags: php, html

I made a WHILE loop for a game I am making that looks like this: UPDATED TO FULL IF STATEMENT

```
if ($switch == 0){
echo '<a href="/index.php">Exit Voting Booth - You May Vote Again Later</a></br>';
echo '<div role="main" id="main"><div class="wrapper">';
echo '<h3>Ballot Questions:</h3></br>';
$query = "SELECT * FROM ballot_questions";
$ballots = mysql_query($query,$link) or die("Unable to select: ".mysql_error());
$x = 1;

//echo $x;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ballots))
{
echo '<h4>'.$row['question'].'<form action="vote_engine.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value= "',$id,'">
Yes:<input type="radio" value="yes" name = "',$x,'">
No:<input type="radio" value="no" name = "',$x,'"></h4></br>';
$x++;
//echo $x;
}
echo '<p><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form></p>';
}
```

Shows in Browser like this:

Test Ballot Question 1

Yes No

Test Ballot Question 2 Yes No

Test Ballot Question 3 Yes No

Test Ballot Question 4 Yes No

The first line always shows up as if there was a /br tag. The rest shows up as I want.

Here is the html output:

> [Exit Voting Booth - You May Vote Again Later](/index.php)
>
> #### Ballot Questions:
>
> Test Ballot Question#1Yes:No:Test Ballot Question #2Yes:No:Test Ballot Question #3Yes:No:Test Ballot Question #4Yes:No:

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Your data is probably to blame; you can reorder the results to see if it's the first item or that particular row that's the culprit.

Comment: Instead of showing us the visual output you should show the html output, but you are not closing tags properly at all

Comment: you need to fix your </br> tags to <br /> my guess is that there is a </br> above this code which is incorrect

Comment: Is your intention to have a `form` per record?

Comment: change the tags to <br /> and still same output

Comment: In line with above suggestions, run your page through an HTML validator: http://validator.w3.org/.  Once you know you have valid HTML, you have a better chance of fixing this.

Comment: Intention is to have one form. The form works and does update mysql fine. I am just getting that break on the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is not produce valid HTML at all. Who knows how browsers are going to try to render this page.

Two things I see off the bat:

1. Your `<br>` tags are not correct.
2. You are starting a bunch of forms and then ending those tags once.

You can fix those with this code:

```
<?php
if ($switch == 0) {
    echo '<a href="/index.php">Exit Voting Booth - You May Vote Again Later</a></br>';
    echo '<div role="main" id="main"><div class="wrapper">';
    echo '<h3>Ballot Questions:</h3><br />'; ; // This was </br>
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ballot_questions";
    $ballots = mysql_query($query, $link) or die("Unable to select: " . mysql_error());
    $x = 1;

    echo '<form action="vote_engine.php" method="post">'; // This will create ONE form
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($ballots)) {
        echo '<h4>' . $row['question'] . '<input type="hidden" name="id" value= "', $id, '">
                Yes:<input type="radio" value="yes" name = "', $x, '">
                No:<input type="radio" value="no" name = "', $x, '">
              </h4>
            <br />'; // This was </br>
        $x++;
    }
    echo '<p><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"></p></form>'; // Switch </p> and </form> tags
}
?>
```

Comment: THANKS! I didn't notice that ---> // This will create ONE form. Works!